# EF Code-first: how to cache DbCompiledModel?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have setup a simple test project for the EF 4.1 RC, using Code-First aproach. What I see, that every call to new MyContext() is taking quite a long time.
I found, that there is a constructor which accept DbCompiledModel and the description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcompiledmodel(v=VS.103).aspx says, that it is good to cache this object, for better performance.
But I can`t find how to get the DbCompiledModel from existing context. And there are no samples on the net.

Comment: Btw. how did you measured that your model creating is slow? Are you sure that is is really construction of your context what makes you perfomance problems?

Comment: That is a very good question, which have just helped me to find the source of slowness. I`m converting a small app from use of in-memory object cache, to EF+SqlCe, and now I found, that there is a silent exception, that causes delay. Not EF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Model is already cached. You can validate it easily by placing breakpoing to your `OnModelCreating` method. It will be hit only first time you create context. If you want to create `DbCompiledModel` manually you must first create `DbModelBuilder` outside of your context. Use its `Build` method and then `Compile` resulting `DbModel`.

Comment: Does this also apply in ASP.NET MVC? For example, each Request will not invoke OnModelCreating for the same App Domain?

Answer (score 7):

Here`s what I found after rethinking. You can get yourself a copy of compiled model with the following code.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var model = modelBuilder.Build(Database.Connection);
        var compliedModel = model.Compile();
    }
```

But, when I passed that model to my context and made some performance tests, and compared them with a plain call to new MyContext(). I found, that context is already caching the compiled model, since the times were identical. So, caching of compiled model, seems to only needed, when it is handcrafted.